# QtCreator: process jom.exe exited with code 3

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator, build-error

I had a working C++/Qt application. I updated MinGW, Qt and Qt Creator to the latest versions, and now I get an error at compile time. This error does not seem to be due to my code, but to the build system.

E.g.:

```
17:11:15: Running steps for project MyTest...
17:11:15: Starting: "C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.0\bin\jom.exe" clean

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
17:11:20: The process "C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.0\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 3.
```

In the project settings there is the message "qmake: No Qt version set. Cannot run qmake."

My source code is just what you get automatically when you create a new application.

I updated the system environment path with the new Qt and QtCreator directories.

I do not know what else to do...

Thank you!

```
---  
Windows 7
MinGW 
Qt 4.8.4
Qt Creator 2.6.0 (based on Qt 4.8.3 32 bit)
```

Comment: Have you checked your build targets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please go to Tools->Options->Build & Run->Kits and check that there is a Qt version set up in the kit you are using.

If not, then check the Qt versions creator detected in Tools->Options->Build & Run->Qt versions. Is the version you want to use there? If not: Add it here.

Then return to the kits page and set one of the kits to use that version. Double check the other information while there.

Now you should be able to build your project. You might need to close/reopen it though.

Initial setup seems to be a bit bumpy... but it works really well once you get over that initial hurdle:-( There are quite some improvements in the next update for this. Check the Qt 5 RC2 packages, the creator included there already contain most of the fixes if you are curious).